# Strange difference. Why different result in FileChooserDialog?

Tags: python, gtk3, introspection

I've battled with the following for a couple of days, and distilled a very compact version of the problem which still shows the issue. The following program shows a basic window, and first opens a `FileChooserDialog`.

Here's the version which fails - it does not show the `Cancel` and `Accept` buttons in the dialog:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import GLib, Gtk

class Script():
    def __init__(self, parent, width = 800):
        self.parent = parent

    def script_file_dialog(self):
        fc = Gtk.FileChooserDialog(
                    parent = self.parent,
                    title = "title",
                    action = Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN,
                    do_overwrite_confirmation = True)
        fc.add_buttons = ("Cancel", Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
                          "Open", Gtk.ResponseType.ACCEPT)

        return fc

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.connect("destroy", lambda x: Gtk.main_quit())
        self.set_default_size(1000, 580)

        self.script = Script(self)

        fc = self.script.script_file_dialog()
        if fc.run() == 1:
            print("one")
        fc.destroy()

        self.show_all()

    def on_test_clicked(self, btn):
        #~ self.script.on_open_script(btn)
        self.script = Script(self)

        fc = self.script.script_file_dialog()
        if fc.run() == 1:
            print("one")
        fc.destroy()

    def run(self):
        Gtk.main()

def main(args):
    mainwdw = MainWindow()
    mainwdw.run()

    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

And the following, almost identical version *does* work as intended.
Note the only difference is when instancing the FileChooserDialog,
the buttons are passed as keyword parameters. This is deprecated, and
produces a warning.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import GLib, Gtk

class Script():
    def __init__(self, parent, width = 800):
        self.parent = parent

    def script_file_dialog(self):
        fc = Gtk.FileChooserDialog(
                    parent = self.parent,
                    title = "title",
                    action = Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN,
                    do_overwrite_confirmation = True,
                    buttons = ("Cancel", Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
                               "Open", Gtk.ResponseType.ACCEPT))

        return fc

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.connect("destroy", lambda x: Gtk.main_quit())
        self.set_default_size(1000, 580)

        self.script = Script(self)

        fc = self.script.script_file_dialog()
        if fc.run() == 1:
            print("one")
        fc.destroy()

        self.show_all()

    def on_test_clicked(self, btn):
        #~ self.script.on_open_script(btn)
        self.script = Script(self)

        fc = self.script.script_file_dialog()
        if fc.run() == 1:
            print("one")
        fc.destroy()

    def run(self):
        Gtk.main()

def main(args):
    mainwdw = MainWindow()
    mainwdw.run()

    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

I tried delaying the showing of the dialog by triggering it by a button
after the main dialog was shown. What's more, I've used the first pattern
in other programs, and it's working there.

It's probably the stay-at-home rules which are slowly getting me crazy...
Anyone sees the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first version has a typo:

```
fc.add_buttons = ("Cancel", Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
                  "Open", Gtk.ResponseType.ACCEPT)
```

should be:

```
fc.add_buttons("Cancel", Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
               "Open", Gtk.ResponseType.ACCEPT)
```

Comment: Great! Cheers, Damian. You can't imagine the hours I've been staring at this!